# Where is the driver folder in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, kernel

I need to access an option.c file inside the path `[linux-src]/drivers/usb/serial/option.c`.
I update my kernel version:

```
    admin@sintrones-abox:~$ uname -r
    5.18.14-051814-generic
```

Inside the folder /usr/src I still have the older kernels directories:

```
admin@sintrones-abox:/usr/src$ ls
backport-iwlwifi-8324            linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-122
linux-headers-5.18.14-051814     Quectel_Linux_USB_Driver
linux-headers-5.4.0-122-generic
```

I tried to search:

```
admin@sintrones-abox:/usr/src$ locate -b '\serial'
/home/admin/drivers/usb/serial
/lib/modules/4.15.0-189-generic/kernel/drivers/tty/serial
/lib/modules/5.4.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/tty/serial
/lib/modules/5.4.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial
/snap/core20/1518/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial
/snap/core20/1581/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial
/usr/src/Quectel_Linux_USB_Driver/drivers/usb/serial
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-122-generic/include/config/serial
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-122-generic/include/config/ir/serial
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-122-generic/include/config/kgdb/serial
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-122-generic/include/config/snd/serial
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-122-generic/include/config/tablet/serial
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-122-generic/include/config/u/serial
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-122-generic/include/config/usb/serial
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-122/drivers/tty/serial
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-122/drivers/usb/serial
/var/lib/snapd/assertions/asserts-v0/serial
```

But none of them contains an `option.c` file. It is automatic generated file from Linux? Where can I find it? How can I re-generate it?

Comment: I suspect it is in Quectel_Linux_USB_Driver. Please be aware that after you change it, you will need to recompile it and install the amended driver into your system. Not trivial but not impossible. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and the rabbit hole.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

After you install linux-source  go to /usr/src and there should be linux-source-5.18.14-xx.tar.bz2.
Once you unzip that all the source files should be in their proper place.

Comment: admin@sintrones-abox:/$ sudo apt-get install -y linux-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-source is already the newest version (4.15.0.189.174).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: How can uninstall the package and reinstall it to have the .tar.bz2?